# ASPOSE.Cell -How to read the calculated value from a AddIn Formula Cell

Tags: c#, aspose-cells

I am using ASPOSE.Cell Component to read an Excel.
I am able to read normal values from cells. But in my excel few cell values are driven by Add-In formulas, which i am  not able to read. When i read the value of those cells using cell[].Value, i am always getting NULL.

Has anyone experienced this?
Please advice.

Thanks
K B B

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Status update:
We are working on this issue with ASPOSE support team, you can follow it on

http://www.aspose.com/community/forums/349499/aspose.cell-to-read-the-calculated-values-using-addin-formulas/showthread.aspx#349499